# macos pyinstaller, missing pandas in executable

Tags: python, pandas, macos, pyinstaller

on mac, I've prepared script which takes all csv form current folder and saves it as json.
after pyinstaller --onefile main.py or pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import pandas main.py
i run application and it says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "main.py", line 1, in 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
> [84164] Failed to execute script main

My script code is:

```
import pandas
import os 
files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for f in files:
    if f.find('csv')>=0 and f.find('~')<0:
        try:
            excel_data_df = pandas.read_csv(f, header=0, delimiter=';')
            real_cols = [x for x in excel_data_df.columns if (not x.startswith("Unnamed: "))]
            excel_data_df = excel_data_df[real_cols]
            json_str = excel_data_df.to_json(orient='records',force_ascii=False) 
            g = open(f.replace('csv','json'), "w")
            g.write(json_str)
            g.close()
        except Exception as e:
            h = open('err.txt', "w")
            h.write(str(e)+' \n')
            h.close()
```

Script works. Run in PyCharm with venv. Pyinstaller command run in PyCharm terminal.

I have tried the same on windows machine. It worked. On mac it doesn't.

Why does it happen? What to do to have proper application?

Comment: Have you installed this module using `pip install pandas` ? It looks like it's missing.

Comment: you should find your python exec path in your mac. use `which python` or `which ipython` to check out.

Comment: @Ferris how checking exe path will help me with missing library?

Comment: @Oo.oO pandas is installed

Comment: in terminal, use `which` is to find the default python Interpreter your use to run the script. if it turns out not the same with  `PyCharm`, your should condsider add the python dir to the linux/unix `$PATH`.